# Login failed & Redirect failed

Tags: php, authentication

1. failed login at `auth.php`. It just can accept 1 user from database
2. failed redirect to `admin.php` on line `header("Location: admin.php");`

**file: auth.php**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); 
$settings_dir = "../settings";
include "$settings_dir/database.php";
$login=mysql_query('SELECT username, password FROM admin ');
$r=mysql_fetch_array($login);
$admin = $r['username'];
$admin_pw = $r['password'];
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = md5($_POST['pass']);
    if (($username == $admin) && ($password ==$admin_pw)) {
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['admin_pw'] = $password;
    }
    header("Location: admin.php");
    exit();
} elseif ((isset($_SESSION['admin']) && isset($_SESSION['admin_pw']) &&$_SESSION['admin'] == $admin && $_SESSION['admin_pw'] == $admin_pw ) || (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")=="")) {
} else {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Admin Login
        </title>
        <LINK REL=STYLESHEET HREF="admin.css" TYPE="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <br>
            <br>
            <fieldset style="width:30%;">
                <legend><b>
                    Admin Login
                    </b></legend>
                <form action="auth.php" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Username
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="user">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Password
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="password" name="pass">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: First of all, you should move to Mysqli / PDO as mysql_query is deprecated. Secondly  -  are the username and password the only records in the database and Third - are they encrypted as MD5 ?

Comment: @user3526204 ‘*encrypted as MD5*’ MD5 is *not* an encryption algorithm.

Comment: Right..it is a cryptographic hash function....but are the values in the database as such ? Also have you tried var_dump $_POST to see what exactly is posted on user and pass ?

Answer (score -1):

```
file: auth.php
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); 


$settings_dir = "../settings";
include "$settings_dir/database.php";

$login=mysql_query('SELECT username, password FROM admin ');
$r=mysql_fetch_array($login);
$admin = $r['username'];
$admin_pw = $r['password'];

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = md5($_POST['pass']);
if (($username == $admin) && ($password ==$admin_pw)) {
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['admin_pw'] = $password;
}
?>
<script>
window.location.href='admin.php';
</script>
<?php

exit();

} elseif ((isset($_SESSION['admin']) && isset($_SESSION['admin_pw']) &&$_SESSION['admin'] == $admin && $_SESSION['admin_pw'] == $admin_pw ) || (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")=="")) {

} else {

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Login</title>
    <LINK REL=STYLESHEET HREF="admin.css" TYPE="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<center>
<br><br>

<fieldset style="width:30%;"><legend><b>Admin Login</b></legend>
<form action="auth.php" method="post">

<table>
<tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit"></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
</fieldset>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
exit();
}
?>
```